# accidentally installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode alongside with Windows in legacy mode

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, bios

I had Windows 10 installed in legacy mode. I accidentally installed Ubuntu alongside it in UEFI mode. Now (spoiler alert) I can only load Ubuntu. Is there any way to move Ubuntu from UEFI to BIOS so I can load either OS.

Thank you.

Comment: Did drive get converted from MBR(msdos) to gpt? If so Windows will not boot, it can only boot in BIOS from MBR. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: ubfan1's suggestion may work; however, that answer does make assumptions about the system's configuration. To clarify and not poke around without making those assumptions, the `parted` output that oldfred wants would be helpful.

Comment: If setting your BIOS back to legacy allows Windows to boot again, then I'd reinstall Ubuntu in legacy mode.

Answer (score 1):

Install grub-pc, set your machine to boot legacy first in the UEFI Settings (formerly known as BIOS), and reboot.  There's not much different between the installs, just the bootloaders.  You can clean up a bit by removing grub-efi and the /etc/fstab mount of the EFI partition at /boot/efi, but that's optional.

Comment: Installing the package might not be enough; it might also be necessary to type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (or whatever the boot device is) and `sudo update-grub`. The [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) might also be helpful -- but only if run from a BIOS-mode boot, perhaps of an Ubuntu installation disk in its "try before installing" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It wasn't the smartest thing to do in the first place. I just reinstalled Ubuntu in legacy mode and everything works fine now. I understand it is a dirty solution but since I had completely new os reinstallation worked fine.